# Using a UNIX Timestamp in Hive

Tags: floating-point, timestamp, hive, unix-timestamp, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to use a FLOAT as a Timestamp for Hive but I'm getting an IllegalArgumentException.  According to the documentation this should be read as seconds in Unix time with decimal precision: https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-types.html#LanguageManualTypes-Timestamps
I'm using Hive 0.10.

Schema: 
`create external table BT_PP (

```
>     Name STRING,

>     Application STRING,

>     PathId STRING,

>     StartTime TIMESTAMP,

>     Dimensions MAP<STRING, STRING>,

>     Values MAP<STRING, DOUBLE>,

>     Failed BOOLEAN,

>     VisitId BIGINT,

>     ResponseTime DOUBLE,

>     Duration DOUBLE,

>     CpuTime DOUBLE,

>     ExecTime DOUBLE,

>     SuspensionTime DOUBLE,

>     SyncTime DOUBLE,

>     WaitTime DOUBLE

> )

> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' ESCAPED BY '\\' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',' MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '='`
```

Example raw row: 
`Web Page Requests;xxx;PT\=115734\;PA\=314959848\;PS\=1725166795;1378315124.621;Complete Uri Path=/<...>;;false;;1616.58935546875;1616.58935546875;642.5269893486796;927.1752303076349;;;`

Query:
`select * from bt_pp where datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), startTime) < 2;`

Error:
`2013-09-09 12:36:25,687 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskStatus: task-diagnostic-info for task attempt_201308221633_0005_m_000001_3 : java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"name":"Web Page Requests","application":"xxx","pathid":"PT=115734;PA=314959848;PS=1725166795","starttime":"1969-12-31 19:00:00","dimensions":{"Complete Uri Path":"/<...>"},"values":{},"failed":false,"visitid":null,"responsetime":2189.27880859375,"duration":2189.27880859375,"cputime":353.1250106477223,"exectime":940.3325603696519,"suspensiontime":null,"synctime":null,"waittime":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"name":"Web Page Requests","application":"xxx","pathid":"PT=115730;PA=314959848;PS=1725166795","starttime":"1969-12-31 19:00:00","dimensions":{"Complete Uri Path":"/<...>"},"values":{},"failed":false,"visitid":null,"responsetime":2189.27880859375,"duration":2189.27880859375,"cputime":353.1250106477223,"exectime":940.3325603696519,"suspensiontime":null,"synctime":null,"waittime":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:673)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:141)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating starttime
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.processOp(FilterOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:654)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
        at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyTimestamp.init(LazyTimestamp.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyStruct.uncheckedGetField(LazyStruct.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyStruct.getField(LazyStruct.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.objectinspector.LazySimpleStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazySimpleStructObjectInspector.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:76)
        ... 18 more`

The error references the timestamp, but uses the Epoch (EST) instead of the value in the row.  You can see in the error "Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating starttime" that it definitely has something to do with that field.

Comment: could you please provide your query here??

Comment: Yes, you need to add your actual query, preferrably the schema of your table. More information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Timestamps

> Timestamps in text files have to use the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]. If they are in another format declare them as the appropriate type (INT, FLOAT, STRING, etc.) and use a UDF to convert them to timestamps.

So you can't simply use a seconds-after-the-epoch float (or integer) value in a TIMESTAMP field, you need to convert it.